# Replace using RegEx outside of text markers

Tags: regex, replace, tags, marker

I have the following sample text and I want to replace '[core].' with something else but I only want to replace it when it is not between text markers ' (SQL):

> PRINT 'The result of [core].[dbo].[FunctionX]' + [core].[dbo].[FunctionX] + '.'
>
> EXECUTE [core].[dbo].[FunctionX]

The Result shoud be:

> PRINT 'The result of [core].[dbo].[FunctionX]' + [extended].[dbo].[FunctionX] + '.'
>
> EXECUTE [extended].[dbo].[FunctionX]

I hope someone can understand this. Can this be solved by a regular expression?

With RegLove

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a single step, and not in an ordinary text editor. If your SQL is syntactically valid, you can do something like this:

First, you remove every string from the SQL and replace with placeholders. Then you do your replace of `[core]` with something else. Then you restore the text in the placeholders from step one:

- Find all occurrences of `'(?:''|[^'])+'` with `'n'`, where `n` is an index number (the number of the match). Store the matches in an array with the same number as `n`. This will remove all SQL strings from the input and exchange them for harmless replacements without invalidating the SQL itself.
- Do your replace of `[core]`. No regex required, normal search-and-replace is enough here.
- Iterate the array, replacing the placeholder `'1'` with the first array item, `'2'` with the second, up to `n`. Now you have restored the original strings.

The regex, explained:

```
'          # a single quote
(?:        # begin non-capturing group
  ''|[^']  #   either two single quotes, or anything but a single quote
)+         # end group, repeat at least once
'          # a single quote
```

JavaScript this would look something like this:

```
var sql = 'your long SQL code';
var str = [];

// step 1 - remove everything that looks like an SQL string
var newSql = sql.replace(/'(?:''|[^'])+'/g, function(m) { 
  str.push(m);
  return "'"+(str.length-1)+"'";
});

// step 2 - actual replacement (JavaScript replace is regex-only)
newSql = newSql.replace(/\[core\]/g, "[new-core]");

// step 3 - restore all original strings
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  newSql = newSql.replace("'"+i+"'", str[i]);
}

// done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (javascript):

```
str.replace(/('[^']*'.*)*\[core\]/g, "$1[extended]");
```

[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ejati4/3/)

Comment: "`PRINT 'The result of ''[core].[dbo].[FunctionX]''' + [core].[dbo].[FunctionX] + '.' EXECUTE [core].[dbo].[FunctionX]`"?

Comment: Have you bothered clicking on the link? Because I don't know where you copy your output from... There is a working example. Go and see it.

Comment: Have you bothered trying with the string I posted? ;-) Because it doesn't work work this string.

Comment: that's not an input, that's invalid SQL. :)

Comment: No, it isn't. Look again. ;-)